# Where is my neo4j installed on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I followed some instruction on the web and installed Neo4j, but not exactly sure where it's installed.

```
bin$ whereis neo4j
neo4j: /usr/bin/neo4j /etc/neo4j /usr/share/neo4j /usr/share/man/man1/neo4j.1.gz

~$ ls /var/lib/neo4j/                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
certificates  data  import  plugins
```

I wanted to install neo4j APOC library, and downloaded apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar and copied it to:

```
/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
```

Then in the Neo4j browser, I typed:

```
return apoc.help('apoc')
```

I got this error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError
Unknown function 'apoc.help' (line 1, column 16 (offset: 15))
"return apoc.help('apoc')"
```

So I think my apoc library wasn't copied into the right place. Where is my neo4j actually installed? I ran this command below. My purpose is to install APOC for neo4j on my Ubuntu machine.

```
$ sudo dpkg -L neo4j
/.
/var
/var/log
/var/log/neo4j
/var/lib
/var/lib/neo4j
/var/lib/neo4j/import
/var/lib/neo4j/plugins
/var/lib/neo4j/data
/var/lib/neo4j/data/databases
/etc
/etc/neo4j
/etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/neo4j
/etc/default
/etc/default/neo4j
/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/neo4j-shell.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/neo4j.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/neo4j-admin.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/neo4j-import.1.gz
/usr/share/neo4j
/usr/share/neo4j/tools
/usr/share/neo4j/tools/2.x-config-migrator.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/bin
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/tools
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/tools/2.x-config-migrator.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j-shell
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j-import
/usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j-admin
/usr/share/neo4j/lib
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-command-line-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jackson-core-asl-1.9.13.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.3-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jersey-servlet-1.19.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-codegen-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-resource-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-ir-3.3-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-http-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-configuration-1.10.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-util-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-servlet-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-csv-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-unsafe-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-server-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/caffeine-2.3.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-bolt-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jsr311-api-1.1.2.r612.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/lucene-analyzers-common-5.5.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jackson-jaxrs-1.9.13.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/mimepull-1.9.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.1-3.1.6.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/parboiled-scala_2.11-1.1.7.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-shell-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-text-1.1.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/server-api-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-matching-3.1.6.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-security-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-kernel-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/scala-reflect-2.11.11.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-frontend-3.2-3.2.5.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-primitive-collections-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-io-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-frontend-2.3-2.3.11.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-2.3-2.3.11.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/opencsv-2.3.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-jmx-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/rhino-1.7R4.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-values-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-common-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-configuration-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-browser-3.0.11.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.2-3.2.5.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-xml-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jline-2.12.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-ir-3.2-3.2.5.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/scala-library-2.11.11.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-logging-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-server-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-logical-plans-3.3-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.2.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-io-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/parboiled-core-1.1.7.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-ssl-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-udc-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graphdb-api-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-dbms-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-compress-1.12.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/bcprov-jdk15on-1.53.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-lucene-upgrade-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jersey-server-1.19.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-graph-algo-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-consistency-check-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jersey-multipart-1.19.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-import-tool-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-webapp-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jersey-core-1.19.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-collections-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-lucene-index-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-index-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/lucene-core-5.5.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/lucene-codecs-5.5.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/bcpkix-jdk15on-1.53.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.3-3.3.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/lucene-queryparser-5.5.0.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/netty-all-4.1.15.Final.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/jetty-security-9.2.22.v20170606.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/neo4j-cypher-compiler-3.1-3.1.6.jar
/usr/share/neo4j/lib/commons-lang3-3.5.jar
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/neo4j
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/neo4j
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/UPGRADE.txt
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/LICENSES.txt.gz
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/README.txt
/usr/share/doc/neo4j/copyright
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/neo4j
/usr/bin/neo4j-shell
/usr/bin/neo4j-import
/usr/bin/neo4j-admin
/lib
/lib/systemd
/lib/systemd/system
/lib/systemd/system/neo4j.service
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`apoc.help` is a [procedure](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/procedures/), not a [function](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/extending-neo4j/cypher-functions/). To invoke a procedure, you must use the `CALL` clause.

Try this:

```
CALL apoc.help('apoc');
```

Comment: I tried this and still received: "There is no procedure with the name `apoc.help` registered for this database instance. Please ensure you've spelled the procedure name correctly and that the procedure is properly deployed."

Comment: Probably my apoc wasn't installed correctly. I simply copied the jar to "/var/lib/neo4j/plugins".

Comment: Did you restart the neo4j server after installing the JAR file?

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the owner and group of the jar file.

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer to download the server version as an archive to unpack it wherever you want. 
After some time, you'll have a lot of versions in // on your dev station.

So Neo4j created "Neo4j desktop" that is a GUI to manage your dbs.
Everything it installs is in ~/.Config/Neo4j Desktop